# ActionListner and ActionPerformed returning action outside of class

Tags: java, string, swing

I created a jpanel outside of this class that has a button that I want the following action performed to be passed too. I am new to programming and not sure how to do this. Couldn´t find help online. b2.setText(b);

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class myJPanel1 extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
        String b = "a";
    JButton jl1;

    public myJPanel1(student st1, myJPanel2 b2)
    {

                super();

        setBackground(Color.yellow);
        //JButton jl1 = new JButton(st1.getInfo());
        jl1 = new JButton(st1.getInfo());
                jl1.addActionListener(this);
                add(jl1);

    }

   @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        double r = Math.random();
        int myNumber = (int)(r*3f);
        if (myNumber == 0){ 

            b = "reading";

        }
        if (myNumber == 1){ 

            b = "talking";

        }
        if (myNumber == 2){ 
            b = "interacting";

            b2.setText(b);

        } 

    }     
}
```

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class myJPanel2 extends JPanel
{

```
JButton b1,b2,b3,b4;

public myJPanel2(student st1)
{
    super();
    setBackground(Color.pink);
    //setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
    b1 = new JButton ("When the user clicks on the button in the UPPER panel");

    add(b1);

    b2 = new JButton("Display here whatsUp from the student in UPPER Panel" );
    add(b2);

    b3 = new JButton("===>>>>You CANNOT create a student here <======" );
    add(b3);

    b4 = new JButton("It has to be the student from the UPPER Panel" );
    add(b4);
}
```

}

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Based on your example `b2.setText` would generate a `NullPointerException` as `b2` is never initialised nor is added to any visible container, also `myJPanel2` doesn't have a `setText` method, so, it wouldn't compile

Answer (score 2):

A JPanel doesn't have a setText() method, so you can't set the text on the panel.

Maybe you are attempting to set the text of the button. In that case you need to define the JButton as an instance variable. Then you invoke setText() on that variable, not on the panel.

```
//myJPanel2 b2;
JButton jl1;

...

//JButton jl1 = new JButton(st1.getInfo());
jl1 = new JButton(st1.getInfo());

...

//b2.setText(b);//this doesn´t work   
jl1.setText(b);
```

Comment: That didn´t do anything but thank you kind sir

Comment: @RossGerard, yes the basic concept will do something. If it doesn't do anything, then you haven't implemented the concept properly. Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates how you tested this. Also class names should start with an upper case character. So fix your code before you repost it.

Comment: What I mean is I tried the changes  recommended and it workds fine for jl1 but that´s not the button I am trying to change with the action. I am trying to change b2 which I added from another class

Comment: Well, in you code you define "b2" as a "myJPanel2" class so that won't work. If you want to update the variable "b2" in another class then you need to pass a reference to the "b2" button to your class the same way you pass the "student" reference to the class.

Comment: I put the new code up. That is what I originally tried before posting the first time. Unfortunatly for me I am still getting errors namely it wants a class for b2 at the b2.setText(b);

Comment: @RossGerard, How many times do I need to repeat myself. "myJPanels" is a JPanel, which does not contain a setText() method. If you want to set the text of a JButton, then you need to pass the button as a reference to your method. Or you create a method in the "jPanel2" class like `getButton() which will return the reference to your b2 button. Then you can update the button. You still have not fixed your code to use proper class names and you still have not posted a `SSCCE` so this is my last comment until you fix the code. If you want help then make an effort.

Comment: Thanks, I cleaned it up for you. You helped me explain the concept. I know what you mean sometimes when I am trying to show somebody a new Combat move they need to see it because they are so unfamiliar with the ideas more than once.That is the same with many people. They often need to be told more than once. It is just a fact of life and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You set text on button but not not repainted it. Call `revalidate();` and then `repaint()`; after setting text.

Comment: I am not sure if repaint is right? I think repaint() has to do with repainting images?

Comment: No, there is no need to invoke revalidate() or repaint(). Swing will automatically repaint a component when a property is changed.

Comment: @RossGerard I've forgot to add revalidate before repaint. Haven't used swing long long time. Swing is a history.

Comment: The code was valid b2.repaint(); but nothing happened when I hit the button